# Why is the staticmethod decorator necessary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

Given that the following code runs without error, why is the `staticmethod` decorator necessary?  What is it actually doing?

```
class Foo:
    def say_hi(name):
        print(f'Hello {name}.')

    @staticmethod
    def say_bye(name):
        print(f'See ya later, {name}.')

my_name = 'Bar...t'
Foo.say_hi(my_name)
Foo.say_bye(my_name)
```

Comment: Without the decorator, `say_bye` would be an instance method. Are you asking why static methods exist in the first place?

Comment: Your non static method needs a self as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods, much like class methods, are methods that are bound to a class rather than its object.

They do not require a class instance creation. So, they are not dependent on the state of the object.

The difference between a static method and a class method is:

Static method knows nothing about the class and just deals with the parameters.
Class method works with the class since its parameter is always the class itself.
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/staticmethod

Comment: Well yes but why is the non-static method callable on the class?